# jQuery z-index and animate problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index

I've got some code which animates my images on click and then adds a z-index to it.

What I need now is to when I click the close button I need it to animate back to its original state and then change the z-index back to how it was.

Currently it changes the z-index and then animates so it looks a bit strange

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/hD72c/)

Is it possible to do?

I've tried putting a `delay` before the z-index change but it still doesn't work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hD72c/1/ updated and fixed

All you need to do is change to `z-index: 1` as a callback at the end of the animation rather then changing it straight away when close is clicked

Comment: cheers mate it's small error but easy to make when you start with jq :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hD72c/3/

I just put the css to replace the original `z-index` in a callback function (instead of using a delay, since `.css()` doesn't add to the animation queue, it executes immediately)