# jquery animating an object to the top layer of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an interesting problem.  I currently have a grid of four block elements, and I would like to enable some behavior to cause the div to grow when clicked on.  The catch is, I am trying to animate it to the top level of the page, aka, I don't want it to dislocate the position of the other divs on the page.

It's difficult to explain, but I want it to kind of be like a modal window with the open animation originating from the element's location.  Like a popup when it's clicked.  Right now I am trying to do this in the click function:

```
$( "#cell" ).animate({
          height:600, width:600, position:'fixed'
        }, 1000, "linear", function(){ alert("all done"); });
```

This animates it bigger, but I was hoping to make it like an overlay.  Has anyone seen anything like this, or a plugin that accomplishes this before?

Comment: you'll need to update the element's z-index.  see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052128/jquery-z-index-and-animate-problem

Comment: You should do this with a css class, not with animate.

Comment: That doesn't help with it pushing all the inner divs around while it animates...

Comment: I suppose, think of it like cloning the element, and then expanding the clone to overlay on the page.

Comment: I think I understand. If you have a box containing some elements, you want to expand the edges of the box outwards while leaving the contents in place. In addition the box moves up/down and all around?

Comment: Kinda, think like this:  there is a box on the left, and right.  The user clicks the left, it would animate to grow, and center in the screen.  The elements under it would not be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the element, absolutely position it over the original and animate the copy.

Press "Add to cart" and see this in action:

http://toys.scholarschoice.ca/products/Active-Play-536/12-Years-Old-Up-563/RipStik-Caster-Board-Silver-p46490/pstart1/

Comment: Seemed to do the trick, this is what I did:`$( "#invitedToChatCell" ).clone().attr('class','cloned_object content_cell').appendTo('#mainContentTable');` and then animated the cloned object

Comment: Haha, well it worked, I made it more generic to work on the other divs now too.  I just have to figure out how to position the clone over the div if it's not in the top left.

Comment: does the animation function work dynamically?  like if I set the left position, and then animate it, it will grow left instead of right?

Comment: Figured out the CSS, but still having that animation problem.  I can't get it to animate from the outside corner inward in all instances...

Comment: This ended up doing the trick.  Just for anyone who may be doing this, make sure you create a deep copy if you have any events you wish to fire inside the clone...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the idea of cloning and animate the clone..

See my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/npg9L/)